# Free action/no action encounter power available to all players?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The DM I play with for encounters passes out these power cards that are either a free action or a non-action (can't remember) encounter power that lets you add to a skill check roll, add a damage die, add a to hit roll, or gain an extra minor action. I can't for the life of me remember what it is called, but he did say its out of either DMG or DMG2, though it may be simply something he designed himself.

Comment: sounds like a house rule to me. There are D&D fortune cards, but they are fundamentally different, you don't happen to have one that you could post do you?

Comment: I agree that those sound like Fortune Cards.  I was involved in a 1 shot where they were used, though I don't remember the exact mechanics other than that you had the card 'til you used it, then on some cue you could draw another afterward.  Here's an index of them so you can see if there are any you recognize: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Fortune_Cards_%284e_Index%29

Comment: Those sound similar to the cards you use in Living Forgotten Realms.  If you list some card names and text I could tell you for sure.

Comment: I know it sounds like a fortune card, but its not (I have seen and used those). Rather than being different cards all of these options are on a single card that he printed and can be used in and out of combat (encounter power basically) to do basically give more oomph to anything from a skill check to an attack.  It may not exist within the game and be some kind of self-made powercard based on things stated in DMG 1 and 2 for 4e, but I wasn't sure and Thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, so I was wrong and it was completely DM fiat w/ him putting in a lot of time to create a power card for his house-rule. Sorry to have wasted your time.

As requested:

The program used to create the power cards: http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/

and

the power card templates: http://www.dungeoncrawl.us/power_cards/

I'll post again when I have an example of the exact power/ability I was talking about.

Comment: Actually I think it's a pretty neat idea for a mechanic so I am glad I got to know about that.

Comment: I will post a version of it (either just the text or if I can link a suitably sized scan of it/jpg I will as well) as soon as I can so you can see exactly what I was rambling about. It was neat because it wasn't game breaking in anyway and helped tie Rollplay and Roleplay together a bit more during combat.